# Aspect not being found during runtime

Tags: java, maven, aspectj

I am trying to add aspectj to a maven project using java 6.0. 
Using 1.4 version of aspectj-maven-plugin and 1.6.11 version of aspectj.

The classes are in an external dependency jar and here is the pom:

```
 <plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
      <complianceLevel>1.6</complianceLevel>
      <source>1.6</source>
      <target>1.6</target>          
      <showWeaveInfo>true</showWeaveInfo>
      <weaveDependencies>
        <weaveDependency>
          <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
          <artifactId>gem</artifactId>
        </weaveDependency>
      </weaveDependencies>          
    </configuration>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <!-- Needs to run before the regular javac compile phase -->
        <phase>process-sources</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>compile</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```

The aspects seem to be applied fine during build time:
Here is a sample:

```
[INFO] --- aspectj-maven-plugin:1.4:compile (default) @ test ---
[INFO] Extending interface set for type 'test.pkg1.pkg2.PaymentEnquiry' (PaymentE
 nquiry.java) to include 'test.pkg1.pkg2.aj.AdditionalPaymentEnquiryMethods'    
(PaymentEnquiryExtensions.aj)
```

But then during runtime, I get the following error:
    java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
    test.pkg1.pkg2.Payment.setDetails(Ljava/util/List;)V

Any idea as why this might be happening would be most helpful.

Comment: Where are the modified class files ending up? Are you sure you're including those instead of the un-enhanced ones on the classpath when you run the code?

Answer (score 0):

The most obvious reason is that there is no method with the signature

```
void setDetails(List)
```

on test.pkg1.pkg2.Payment. It doesn't seem much like an AspectJ problem--more of a wrong-code-on-the-runtime-classpath problem.